# Как сделать область для рисования определенного размера. C++

Tags: c++, winapi

Я хочу сделать область черного цвета, которая располагается в нижнем левом углу экрана и в которой я смогу рисовать не выходя за ее пределы. Буду благодарен если покажите маленький примерчик и закрепите все ссылкой на сайт с теорией.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    case WM_PAINT:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
// начинаем отрисовку
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
// получаем область окна (пригодится для того что-бы узнать координаты нижней точки окна
        RECT clientrc;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &clientrc);
// создаём переменную которая будет хранить область для рисования
        RECT rc;
        rc.left = 0;
// rc.bottom это и будет нижняя точка окна
        rc.bottom = clientrc.bottom;
        rc.top = clientrc.bottom - 100;
        rc.right = 100;
// заливаем область чёрным (то что число 2 отвечает за чёрный я узнал методом подбора)
        FillRect(hdc, &rc, (HBRUSH)2);
// заканчиваем рисовать
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
```

Чтобы не выходить за прределы: rc.top - верхняя точка твоей области, rc.right - правая, остальные в даном случае ноли, размер области указан небыл, для примера я сделал 100 на 100;

Если нужно ограничить возможность выхода за пределы, то создайте окно стиля popup там где вам надо и рисуйте в нём, способ не идеальный, но рабочий.

Пример:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

HWND hwnd2;
HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
HBITMAP membmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 800, 800);

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc2(HWND hwnd2, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME2[] = L"Sample Window Class2";

    WNDCLASS wc2 = { };

    wc2.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc2;
    wc2.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc2.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME2;

    RegisterClass(&wc2);

    // Create the window.
    int wndposx = 200;
    int wndposy = 200;
    int wndwidth = 550;
    int wndheight = 550;
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"TEST1",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        wndposx, wndposy, wndwidth, wndheight,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    HWND hwnd2 = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME2,                     // Window class
        L"TEST2",    // Window text
        WS_POPUP,           // Window style

        // Size and position
        wndposx+7, wndposy + wndheight - 100 - 7, 100, 100,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    ShowWindow(hwnd2, nCmdShow);
    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(1));


        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    }
    return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc2(HWND hwnd2, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps2;
        HDC hdc2 = BeginPaint(hwnd2, &ps2);
        RECT clrc2;
        GetClientRect(hwnd2, &clrc2);
        clrc2.right = 1000;
        FillRect(hdc2, &clrc2, (HBRUSH)2);
        EndPaint(hwnd2, &ps2);
    }
    return 0;

    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd2, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Сайтов которые хорошо розъясняют win api не находил, этот пример для gdi, на gdi+ и direct2d, которые входать к win api это как-то по другому реализуется.

Comment: К сожалению ваш код не позволяет игнорировать рисование в не черного прямоугольника.

Comment: IntersectClipRect а вот эта функция как раз обрезает все, что не в ходит в ее область ))

Comment: Попробуйте создать paintstruct и в параметр RECT впихнуть rc, дальше beginpaint с этой paintstruct, завтра сяду за компютер и скажу более подробно

Comment: Ну или так, если это работает

Comment: SelectClipRgn так же работает функция

Comment: Это должно просто обрезать, тоесть при перерисовке может быть мерцание, то что я выше написал, должно просто не выводить на экран то что не входит в область

Comment: А вот мне нужно отрисовать текст в правой части экрана, а потом рисовать только в левом нижнем углу, но функции которые я написал выше они просто обрезают все что не входит. Если вы знает, как сделать то что мне нужно добавьте в свой ответ пожалуйста я приму его.

Comment: Ничего нормального не нашёл, но можно прото создть окно стиля popup там где тебе надо и что-бы не выходить за границы, рисовать в нём.

Comment: А можете показать пример.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста! Я получается делаю все как при создании главного окна. То есть WNDCLASS заполняю, регистрирую, создаю окно с 3 параметром = `WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER`. Потом показываю и обновляю окно. И все отлично создается, но вот можно сделать так, чтобы расположение popup окна было относительно главного окна. То есть в CreateWindow при передаче x = 50 и y = 50 окно создавалось в левом верхнем углу не экрана, а главного окна и тогда проблема решена.

Comment: Сделал пример, -7 в координатах создания второго окна подобрано вручную, и как я понял зависит от стиля окна, если главное POPUP то -7 не надо